# Why is data suddenly being pasted in Excel as a single cell when copying from Google Docs?

Tags: google-sheets

I have been using Google Docs for some time now and have been able to copy certain sections of columns of the spreadsheet and paste it into an Excel sheet and up until now it has transferred exactly perfect. Now, it only pastes it into Excel all in just one cell. I have tried using all the different ways to copy and paste and it still puts the data in one cell as though the data is not being seen in columns.

Any suggestions as to what is happening and why it is happening all of a sudden?

Comment: Have you switched to the [new Google Spreadsheets](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3541068?hl=en), by chance?

Comment: I recommend using the "Send Feedback" or "Report an Issue" feature when you find a bug in a Google service. This sounds like a new bug since it used to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have a temporarily solution:

- Right-click the target excel cell
- Choose **Paste special**
- Choose *Text*

[image]